# Python: Transform Output and visit HTTP

Tags: python, http

I have this subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/home/pi/script','-c' "echo '$OUTPUT'"])
```

in `$OUTPUT`, I will recieve a URL.

1. How can I transform the `$OUTPUT` in to a String(URL)?
2. How can I visit the URL (is a Website with only one number 1-5) and get the Integer from the URL back into a Integer variable number?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could use this :

```
# Assume cmd = the process you want to execute with its parameters
# In your case, cmd = ['/home/pi/script','-c' "echo '$OUTPUT'"]
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
result = pipe.stdout.read()
#=> Result contains your URL, as a String
```

Comment: The return of subprocess.call is not a pipe, and neither is is the object that you later use, it's an integer. You are thinking of subprocess.Popen.

Comment: It's still not a pipe, though.

Comment: import urllib
giveTheInt = [urllib.urlopen(url)]

But i receive only:

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out.

The wireless it's ok, I have a connection to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

"1. How can I transform the $OUTPUT in to a String(URL)?"

That's what `"echo '$OUTPUT'"` does. You then read it from the stdout pipe of the subprocess object. (Which means you need to use `subprocess.Popen()`)

"2. How can I visit the URL (is a Website with only one number 1-5) and get the Integer from the URL back into a Integer variable number?"

Use `urllib`, or in Python 3, `http.request`.

Comment: Regebo with the library urllib i have this problem:             import urllib giveTheInt = [urllib.urlopen(url)]                                              But i receive only: IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out. The wireless it's ok, I have a connection to the internet.

Comment: @user1865863: All you do is open the connection. You also need to `read()` from it to get a result. For further problems, start a new question.